# Find invocations of subclass method

Tags: java, eclipse, search, call, invocation

For context, say I have these classes:

```
public class Foo {
     public void doStuff() {}
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
     @Override
     public void doStuff() {}
}

public class Zig extends Foo {
     @Override
     public void doStuff() {}
}
```

I'm trying to find *only* calls to `Bar#doStuff()`.

I've tried:

- Java Search for `Bar.doStuff`
- "Open Call Hierarchy" on `Bar#doStuff()`

but they appear to return calls to both `Bar.doStuff()` *and* `Foo.doStuff()` **and** `Zig.doStuff()`. Is there something else I need to do, or am I misunderstanding the results I'm getting?

Answer (score 2):

To find the calls which are *definitely* from `Bar`, you can mark `Bar#doStuff` as `@Deprecated`, and then create a new "Problems" view with a filter to find just these messages.

to create the new Problems view:

1. open default Problems view
2. click triangle and choose `New Problems View`
3. in new view, click triangle and choose `Configure Contents`
4. On the left, check only `Errors/Warnings in Project`
5. set the Text `contains` filter (under `Description` heading) as appropriate

**Note**: this will not find cases where `Bar`s are stored as `Foo`s, e.g.:

```
Foo f = new Bar();
f.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, due to polymorphism, there's not a good way for the IDE to know that a given Foo *isn't* potentially a Bar -- so it will show you all calls to `doStuff`. I suppose it could do more analysis to determine that the concrete type of a `Foo` really is a `Foo` -- for example, in the case:

```
final Foo foo = new Foo();
```

it is definitely *not* a `Bar` -- but that's a lot of work for little benefit.

You will notice the same holds true for interfaces and their implementations, at least in Eclipse.

Comment: ok, that much makes sense. I've updated question though, as I'm also getting matches for `Zig`s, which are definitely not `Bar`s.